# Which code snippet executes faster?

Tags: java, android

I can do same thing by two types of code snippet.

First Way:

```
String makeDate = Integer.toString(now.year) + Integer.toString(now.month) + Integer.toString(now.monthDay);
```

Or Second Way:

```
String makeDate = now.year + "" + now.month + "" + now.monthDay;
```

My question is:

1. Which method is preferable [First way or Second way]?
2. Which code snippet will execute faster?

Comment: Use whatever you find the most readable. You would need to execute this billions and billions of times to notice a difference.

Comment: They will both be executed in constant time therefore exec time sure won't be an issue..... Having said that the second way is more elegant in my opinion, there's no need to wrap anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two snippits you show are nearly identical.

a `String` in Java is *immutable*; it can't be changed. When using the concatenation operator (`+`) the compiler actually generates code using a `StringBuilder`

For example your second snippit becomes:

```
String makeDate = new StringBuilder()
                   .append(now.year)
                   .append("")
                   .append(now.month)
                   .append("")
                   .append(now.monthDay)
                   .toString();
```

You can look at the generated bytecode to see this. Java comes with a program `javap` that allows you to look at your compiled `.class`.

I created a simple `main()` to provide minimal bytecode:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String makeDate = Integer.toString(1) + Integer.toString(1) + Integer.toString(1);
    System.out.println(makeDate);
}
```

Which produces:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=2, args_size=1
         0: new           #2                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
         3: dup           
         4: invokespecial #3                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
         7: iconst_1      
         8: invokestatic  #4                  // Method java/lang/Integer.toString:(I)Ljava/lang/String;
        11: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
        14: iconst_1      
        15: invokestatic  #4                  // Method java/lang/Integer.toString:(I)Ljava/lang/String;
        18: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
        21: iconst_1      
        22: invokestatic  #4                  // Method java/lang/Integer.toString:(I)Ljava/lang/String;
        25: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
        28: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
        31: astore_1      
        32: getstatic     #7                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
        35: aload_1       
        36: invokevirtual #8                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        39: return
```

Versus:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int i = 1;
    String makeDate = i + "" + i + "" + i;
    System.out.println(makeDate);
}
```

Produces:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=3, args_size=1
         0: iconst_1      
         1: istore_1      
         2: new           #2                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
         5: dup           
         6: invokespecial #3                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
         9: iload_1       
        10: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
        13: ldc           #5                  // String 
        15: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
        18: iload_1       
        19: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
        22: ldc           #5                  // String 
        24: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
        27: iload_1       
        28: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
        31: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
        34: astore_2      
        35: getstatic     #8                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
        38: aload_2       
        39: invokevirtual #9                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        42: return
```

*Technically* the latter is probably faster at some scale that is nearly immeasurable (< 1ns) but for all practical purposes it doesn't matter; use whichever you like.